# How to use timers in Linux kernel device drivers?

Tags: c, linux, timer, linux-kernel, driver

I want to implement a counter in Linux device drivers which increments after every fixed interval of time. I want to do this with the help of timers. A sample code snippet would be very useful.

Comment: How often do you want to increment this? Why you even need this? (there are some counters here already, e.g. `jiffles`)

Comment: I want to increment say after 10 msec. Can you give some more info regarding how to use jiffles

Comment: @Pat The OP is asking how to create a timer in kernel space. While `setitimer` sets a timer in user space.

Answer (score 13):

Have a look at following article [IBM Developerworks: Timers and Lists](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-timers-list/)

There is a small example of how to use Linux kernel timers (included it here for convenience, comments are from myself, removed printk messages)

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/timer.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static struct timer_list my_timer;

void my_timer_callback( unsigned long data )
{
     /* do your timer stuff here */
}

int init_module(void)
{
  /* setup your timer to call my_timer_callback */
  setup_timer(&my_timer, my_timer_callback, 0);
  /* setup timer interval to 200 msecs */
  mod_timer(&my_timer, jiffies + msecs_to_jiffies(200));
  return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
  /* remove kernel timer when unloading module */
  del_timer(&my_timer);
  return;
}
```

Comment: My "edit queue is full", so I can't post this fixed link to the IBM blog post: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-timers-list/

Answer (score 7):

Around Linux kernel 4.15 release, **void setup_timer(timer, function, data);** became obsolete with an intent to remove it completely.

Instead, now we have to use

```
void timer_setup(
struct timer_list *timer, 
void (*callback)(struct timer_list *),
unsigned int flags
);
```

This can be found in **linux/timer.h** file.

Here's a full example of **module_with_timer.c**

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/jiffies.h>
#include <linux/timer.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static struct timer_list my_timer;

void my_timer_callback(struct timer_list *timer) {
  printk(KERN_ALERT "This line is printed after 5 seconds.\n");
}

static int init_module_with_timer(void) {
  printk(KERN_ALERT "Initializing a module with timer.\n");

  /* Setup the timer for initial use. Look in linux/timer.h for this function */
  timer_setup(&my_timer, my_timer_callback, 0);
  mod_timer(&my_timer, jiffies + msecs_to_jiffies(5000));

  return 0;
}

static void exit_module_with_timer(void) {
  printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, cruel world!\n");
  del_timer(&my_timer);
}

module_init(init_module_with_timer);
module_exit(exit_module_with_timer);
```

And the Makefile is

```
obj-m = module_with_timer.o

# Get the current kernel version number
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

**Note:** In real life programming, it is better to check the version of the kernel we are compiling for and then use an then appropriately start the timer.

References:
https://lwn.net/Articles/735887/

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what you exactly want to do, you can directly use `jiffies` to measure time, as it has been suggested in the comments. You can also use kernel timers, and given the information in your question, they seem to be a better fit.

The kernel timers API is quite intuitive:

```
#include <linux/timer.h>
struct timer_list {
        /* ... */
        unsigned long expires;
        void (*function)(unsigned long);
        unsigned long data;
};

void init_timer(struct timer_list *timer);
struct timer_list TIMER_INITIALIZER(_function, _expires, _data);

void add_timer(struct timer_list * timer);
int del_timer(struct timer_list * timer);
```

So you would just need to define a timer function and then initialize and start the timer.

You have several sources to further learn about this topic:

- [Understanding the Linux Kernel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005652). This book is a sort of bible for the kernel. It is somehow outdated in some areas, but still a really good source of information.
- [Linux Device Drivers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005903). This is a very useful book when developing device drivers. There is an online version too [here](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/). The chapter dealing with time, timers, etc. is chapter 7. This book may be also a bit outdated since it is from 2005 too.
- [Linux Kernel Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329468). I have not checked this book, but the good point is that it is much newer (from 2010), so you may find some updated information compared to the previous two books.